# How could I add the content of the skipped row to the previous row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datafrme like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'label':['a','C','D','E','b','b','c','c','c'], 'text':['a','c','d','e','b','b','c','c','c'],'title':['a','c','d','e','b','b','c','c','c']})
```

[image: the original dataframe]

How could I add the content of the skipped row to the previous row when 'C','D','E' appear as a sequence.
The ideal output would be:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'label':['a','C','D','E','b','b','c','c','c'], 'text':['a','c','d','e','b','b','c','c','c'],'title':['a','c(e)','d','e','b','b','c','c','c']})
```

[image: the ideal output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `shift`

```
s = test['label']
idx = s.eq('C')&s.shift(-1).eq('D')&s.shift(-2).eq('E')
idx = idx[idx].index
test.loc[idx, 'title']+='('+test.shift(-2).loc[idx,'title']+')'
```

input:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'label':['a','C','D','E','b','b','C','D','E'],
                     'text': ['a','c','d','e','b','b','c','c','c'],
                     'title':['a','c','d','e','b','b','c','c','c']})
```

output:

```
  label text title
0     a    a     a
1     C    c  c(e)
2     D    d     d
3     E    e     e
4     b    b     b
5     b    b     b
6     C    c  c(c)
7     D    c     c
8     E    c     c
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! '(e)' is not a fixed value. I'd like to add the value at the column 'text' and 'E''s row. For this example the value is test.iloc[1]['title'] (i.g.'e'). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: and the 'C','D','E' sequence may appear multiple times in this datadrame

Comment: @Alina I updated the answer, as you will see it works for all occurrences and it's easy to access variable values.